# Can I use a transfer learning in facebook prophet?

Tags: time-series, facebook-prophet

I want my prophet model to predict values for every 10 minute interval over the next 24h (e.g. 24*6=144 values).

Let's say I've trained a model on a huge (over 900k of rows) `.csv` file where sample row is 
...

```
ds=2018-04-24 16:10, y=10
ds=2018-04-24 16:20, y=14
ds=2018-04-24 16:30, y=12
```

...

So I call `mode.fit(huge_df)` and wait for 1-2 seconds to receive 144 values.

And then an hour passes and I want to tune my prediction for the following (144 - 6) 138 values given a new data (6 rows).

How can I tune my existing prophet model without having to call  `mode.fit(huge_df + live_df)` and wait for some seconds again? I'd like to be able to call `mode.tune(live_df)` and get an instant prediction.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware this is not really a possibility. I think they use a variant of the BFGS optimization algorithm to maximize the posterior probability of the the models. So as I see it the only way to train the model is to take into account the whole dataset you want to use. The reason why transfer learning works with neural networks is that it is just a weight (parameter) initialization and back propagation is then run iteratively in the standard SGD training schema. Theoretically you could initialize the parameters to the ones of the previous model in the case of prophet, which might or might not work as expected. I'm however not aware that something of the likes is currently implemented (but since its open-source you could give it a shot, hopefully reducing convergence times quite a bit).

Now as far as practical advice goes. You probably don't need all the data, just tail it to what you really need for the problem at hand. For instance it does not make sense to have 10 years of data if you have only monthly seasonality. Also depending on how strongly your data is autocorrelated, you may downsample a bit without loosing any predictive power. Another idea would be to try an algorithm that is suitable for online-learning (or batch) - You could for instance try a CNN with dilated convolution.

Answer (score 0):

Time Series problems are quite different from usual Machine Learning Problems. When we are training cat/dog classifier, the feature set of cats and dogs are not going to change instantly (evolution is slow). But when it comes to the time series problems, training should happen, every time prior to forecasting. This becomes even more important when you are doing univariate forecasting (as is your case), as only feature we're providing to the model is the past values and these value will change at every instance. Because of these concerns, I don't think something like transfer learning will work in time series.

Instead what you can do is, try converting your time series problem into the regression problem by use of rolling windowing approach. Then, you can save that model and get you predictions. But, make sure to train it again and again in short intervals of time, like once a day or so, depending upon how frequently you need a forecast.